# NSMutableURLRequest and Argument labels error

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting an error that says "Argument labels '(URL:, cachePolicy:, timeoutInterval:)' do not match any available overloads" and I can not find out how to fix this does anyone know? I am using Swift 3.0 and XCode 8.3.2
[Here is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLrR1.png)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
extension UIViewController {

    func makeImageViewWithColor(_ color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect (x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image:UIImage =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
    //Function Alert View
    func alertView(title:String, message:String, alertStyle:UIAlertControllerStyle, alertAction:UIAlertAction) {
        let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: alertStyle)
        alert.addAction(alertAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    //Function query to server

    func queryToServer(urlSource:String, postString:String, result:@escaping (_ dataResult:NSData?, _ errorResult:NSError) -> ()) {
        let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: urlSource)!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest (URL: url, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.HTTPBody = glGetString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    result(dataResult: data, errorResult: nil)
                } else {
                    result(dataResult: nil, errorResult: error)
                }
            })
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code as text, not as image !

Comment: oops sorry im new to this site :)

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use `NSMutableURLRequest` in Swift 3 at all.**

Use Swift 3 native syntax instead, there are new structs `URL` and `URLRequest`.

The `var` keyword makes the request mutable.

```
let url = URL(string: urlSource)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
```

PS: The issue in your code is the uppercase `URL` parameter label.

---

Edit: The Swift 3 equivalent of the method `queryToServer` is:

```
func queryToServer(urlSource:String, postString:String, result:@escaping (Data?, Error?) -> ()) {
    let url = URL(string: urlSource)!
    var request = URLRequest (url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            result(data, error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

The error check in the dispatch block is useless. Either the data is valid than the error is `nil` and vice versa. On the other hand you have to `resume` the data task to start it and `glGetString` is probably `postString`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! This fixes the error but now all the code in the //Function query to server is messed up. :( Errors all over the place, how should I write the rest of the code in this function? I am new to Swift 3.0 and it is taking a long time to find out all the new things! This is the last step to get my app working correctly

Comment: Click on the red error "button" on the left side of the error line. In most cases the compiler suggests a fix. For example `HTTPMethod` and `HTTPBody` are lowercased `http...`

Comment: This worked for most of the lines but for         request.httpBody = glGetString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) I get 
Value of type '(GLenum) -> UnsafePointer<GLubyte>!' has no member 'dataUsingEncoding'         and for      result(data as! NSData, nil) i get  Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'NSError'

Comment: Please read my Swift 3 code carefully in the answer and also the comment at the end.

Comment: thank you so much for the updated answer it works like a charm! How long have you been working with Swift 3.0?

Comment: Since its introduction about one year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Argument label is compulsory from swift 3.0

```
    public init(url URL: URL, cachePolicy: NSURLRequest.CachePolicy, timeoutInterval: TimeInterval)
```

In above method, Aurgument lables are,

1. url
2. cachePolicy
3. timeoutInterval

So provide, your first parameter as "**url**" not "**URL**"

Answer (score 0):

Change `NSURL` to `URL` and make caps `URL` in function parameter as small letters

```
let url = URL(string: urlSource)!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```